# Eclipselink: Column length and mb4 for temporary table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, eclipselink

We are using Eclipselink 2.7 and have set the Maria-DB to coalition type UTF8-mb4. In principal the setup works great except for a defined `DELETE` statement. For this Eclipselink wants to execute

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TL_tf (SHA1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, VALUE VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (SHA1))`

which fails cause MariaDB rejects the command due to size restrictions, i.e. SHA1 is too long for together with UTF8-MB4 settings for PRIMARY KEY.

Setting `@Column(length=100)` is ignored by the Eclipselink.

Is there a way to change the settings either on MariaDB or with Eclipselink?

Answer (score 0):

Since SHA1 is only 160 bits / 20 bytes / 40 hex, there is no reason to use 255.  Instead:

```
CHAR(40) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

or use `UNHEX(SHA1(...))` and store in the smaller

```
BINARY(20)
```

Using hashes for a `PRIMARY KEY` does not scale well.  Once the table is too big to be fully cached, accesses to the table become I/O-bound.  This can be a serious problem for huge tables.